# A proof that $\{\sum_{i=1}^{m}s_iX_i : s_i\geq 0,\sum_{i=1}^{m} s_i =1 \}$ where $X_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex and compact.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, solution-verification, convex-analysis, compactness

I would like that the set of convex combination of $m$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex and compact.

The set we are interested in is $A = \{\sum_{i=1}^{m}s_iX_i : s_i\geq 0,\sum_{i=1}^{m} s_i =1 \}$.

Here is my attempt :

First we consider $X_1=\sum_{i=1}^{m}s_iX_i$ and $X_2 = \sum_{i=1}^{m}t_iX_i$ two points in A and $s\in[0,1]$.

We have $sX_1 + (1-s)X_2 = s\sum_{i=1}^{m}s_iX_i + (1-s)\sum_{i=1}^{m}t_iX_i = \sum_{i=1}^{m}(ss_i + (1-s)t_i)X_i$ and $ss_i+(1-s)t_i\geq 0$ for all $i\in\{1,m\}$. Moreover $\sum_{i=1}^{m}(ss_i+(1-s)t_i) = s\sum_{i=1}^{m}s_i+\sum_{i=1}^{m}t_i -s\sum_{i=1}^{m}t_i = s+1-s=1$.

Thus $A$ is convex. To show that it is compact we will use the sequential compactness. First we see that $A$ is bounded. Indeed as we consider a finite family of points $(X_i)_{i=1}^{m}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ we know there exists $M>0$ such that :

$\lVert X_i\rVert\leq M\quad\forall i\in\{1,..,m\}$. It implies that $\lVert\sum_{i=1}^{m}s_iX_i\rVert\leq\sum_{i=1}^{m}s_i\lVert X_i\rVert\leq\sum_{i=1}^{m}s_iM = M$

Now we want to show that $A$ is closed. Consider $(Y_p)_{p} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}s_{i,p}X_i\right)_p$ a sequence in $A$ that converges to $Y$ and we see that the sequence is entirely determined by $s_{p} = (s_{1,p},...,s_{m,p})$. First we need to remark that

$\forall p\in\mathbb{N} : s=(s_{1,p},...,s_{m,p})\in B =\{z\in\mathbb{R}^{m} : z_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^{m}z_i =1\}$

But this set is compact :

$\forall z\in B : \lVert z\rVert_{\infty}\leq 1$ so it is bounded.

B is the $n$ times cartesian produt of the closed set $[0,\infty)$ intersected with the hyperplane $\sum_{i=1}^m z_i = 1$ so it is closed.

The convergence of $(Y_p)_p$ is determined by the convergence of $(s_p)_p$, this means that $(s_p)_p$ is convergent since $(Y_p)_p$ converges. But $(s_p)_p\in B$ so there exists a subsequence $(s_{\varphi(p)})_{p\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $s=(s_1,...,s_m)\in B$, this implies that $(s_p)_{p\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $s\in B$

Thus $(Y_p)_p$ converges to $\sum_{i=1}^{m}s_iX_i\in A$. This shows that $A$ is closed and we conclude that $A$ is compact.

Is this correct ? Have you an elegant proof to propose ?

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an elegant argument, don't try to prove $A$ is compact by proving it is sequentially compact. Instead, show $A$ is the continuous image of a compact set.

You already showed that $S = \{(s_1,\ldots,s_m) : s_i \geq 0, \sum s_i = 1\}$ is a compact subset of $\mathbf R^m$. Your set $A$ is the image of $S$ under the function $f \colon \mathbf R^m \to \mathbf R^n$ where
$$
f(t_1,\ldots,t_m) = t_1X_1 + \cdots + t_mX_m.
$$
Since addition $\mathbf R^n \times \mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R^n$ and scalar multiplication $\mathbf R \times \mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R^n$ are continuous, $f$ is continuous. The continuous image of a compact set is compact, so $A = f(S)$ is compact.

Comment: Wow this was literally right in front of me but I didn't see it, thank you very much.